# Android MVVM Light Transitions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I want to know if its possible to apply a scene transition when navigating between pages using the MVVM Light Navigation Service or if there is a way to accomplish this with mvvm pattern at all, since the transition is applied on the activity options.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english :(

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Sharath, I was thinking about doing a custom navigation service to deal with the transitions. But how to make the navigation service apply the platform-specific transitions since the navigation is handled by the view model? Am I missing something?

Comment: hi found any solution for that so far ?

Comment: Not yet. I'm doing some other stuff at the moment, but I'll come back to this as soon as possible and will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using MVVMlight you'll get the MVVM light's default transition for push and pop out of the stack.

if you want customized transition you've to implement the mvvmlight's navigation service on your own.

the link explains how to implement your won navigation service

https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/07/22/navigation-using-mvvm-light/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was my first thought too. But how to make the navigation service apply the platform-specific transitions since the navigation is handled by the view model? Am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest u to find a way on how you can make a platform specific navigation in view model then its a matter of comparison in view model on which transition to choose from depending on the platfom it consumes

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on that. If I come up with a way to do this on my own, I'll share my solution here for others who are facing the same wall. Thanks again for replying.

Comment: That'd be helpful !